# Hide element outside the ng-view DOM based on route

Tags: angularjs, routes

**Question:**

How can I add a "Login" view/route to my angular app that hides an element that is outside the `ng-view` DOM?

**Situation:**

In my Angular page, I have a navigation tree view on the left and the main view in the center:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-controller="TreeController">
        <div treeviewdirective-here>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 content" ng-view="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Each node in the treeview changes the location using something like `window.location.hash = '#/' + routeForTheClickedItem;`.

Using the standard routing, this works great, i.e. the tree is not reloaded each time, but only the main "window".

**Problem:**

I want to add a login functionality with a login view. For this view, the treeview should not be visible - only after the login. To achieve this with the normal routing, I know I could move the `ng-view` one level up, i.e. embed the treeview into each view - but this would result in the treeview being reloaded with every route change.

Is there an easy alternative that allows me to check what page is displayed in the ng-view? Or check some other variable set during the routing? Then I could use something like:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-controller="TreeController" ng-show="IsUserLoggedIn">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a controller at the top div level.

Something like:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
```

and in `MainController` inject a `Session`. Something like `Session` is enough to decide whether to show the tree.

Here's an example of `MainController`:

```
_app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, SessionService) {
    $scope.user = SessionService.getUser();
});
```

Here's an example of `SessionService`:

```
_app.factory('SessionService', function() {
    var user = null;
    return {
        getUser : function() {
            return user;
        },
        setUser : function(newUser) {
            user= newUser;
        }
    };
});
```

Of course, when you login you must set the user to the `SessionService`. Therefore, a `SessionService` has to be injected into your `LoginController`, too.

And finally, your html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-controller="TreeController">
        <div ng-hide="user == null" treeviewdirective-here>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 content" ng-view="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but this doesn't watch 'user' so that treeview is hidden when user logged out

Answer (score 3):

You could listen for a routeChangeSuccess outside ng-view

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
//do something here
});
```

hope that helps, you can catch me on angularjs IRC - maurycyg