# Is it possible to impact visibility of a DOM element outside of view?

Tags: html, angularjs, controller, typescript

My question is very similar to [Hide element outside the ng-view DOM based on route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144227/hide-element-outside-the-ng-view-dom-based-on-route)

If possible I would like to have a `TypeScript` solution that allows to assign a value to `ng-show` property of an element outside of `ng-view` from my existing controllers.

I tried assigning a value to `$rootScope` property but it was not visible in index.html outside of the view.

Here's what I tried in controller constructors:

`$rootScope.isForm = "true";` in one, and `$rootScope.isForm = "false";` in another.

Inside my **index.html** I have the following:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    ....
    <form <form class="navbar-form navbar-input-group" ng-show="$rootScope.IsForm">
     ...
    </form>
    ...
</div>
...
<div "ng-view">
...
</div>
```

How should I go about it?  Is there still a solution using `$rootScope`?

Comment: If it is outside the scope of your controllers, you will need to do it with vanilla js and css.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `$rootScope` inside your controllers and modify it there. i.e.

```
class FooController{
    static $inject = ['$rootScope'];
    constructor(public $rootScope){
         // You can also do this based on some user action. 
         // Just a demo of how : 
         this.$rootScope.IsForm = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: As `$rootScope` is a single object per application why do I need to prefix the assignment with `this`? Could you please explain or point to an existing explanation?

Comment: You don't need to. I just made it a public member of the controller to show you can use it as a member 'public $rootScope'